# Cognito Form change checkbox choices using JavaScript

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a requirement to load checkbox choices dynamically so I need to set the form field options via JavaScript, after Cognito.load(). I realize I can pre fill the choices which selects the existing choices but I need to be able to define (change) the options for the choices once the form loads.

Answer (score 0):

The Choice field does not currently support dynamic content. The best way to get close to that would be to first use multiple Yes/No Fields, then change the `Show This Field` option to `When`. Make a new field and set `Show This Field` to `Never`. When your page loads the Cognito form, pre-fill that hidden field with the information that you can use to conditionally hide or show the individual checkboxes.

The limitation to this is that you can not dynamically create new options on the fly.